# SSRS: Jump To Different Page Within Same RDL File Using Action Textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2012, textbox, action, ssrs-2012, page-break

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012. I have 4 matrix views on my .rdl file and on each matrix view, in the General tab, I selected "Add a page break after" on each Matrix.

So basically, when previewing, it'll show each report on it's own separate page, 4 in total. Above each matrix, I have 4 text boxes with each name of the report in each text box.

[image]

Basically, I want to add an action to these text boxes that say if user is looking at Page 1 with has report #1, they can click on Report #4 and it will take them to Page 4 to view Report #4, or when click on Report #3 it will take them to Page 3 with that report.

When I go to textbox properties and click on Action, how do I write javascript code for that to happen? Or any code that will help it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Bookmark` property of each matrix and the `Action` property present in the textbox.

This is an example to link the textbox Report #1 1 to the Matrix 1. Select the matrix and press `F4`, look for the `Other` node and set `Bookmark` property to `Report1`, as follows:

[image]

Now go to the textbox you want to click to go to the matrix, right click it and select `Textbox Properties...` / `Action` tab and type `Report1` in the `Select Bookmark:` input.

[image]

> Note in the `Bookmark` property you input can any string, just be sure to
> use the same string in the `Action` property of the textbox.

Do the same for each textbox and matrix.

Comment: Thank you @alejandro, I appreciate your help, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!!